# Use different cell style in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to create a simple example, where I want to use another `UITableViewCellStyle`. In my example it is `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`. I added a `UITableViewController` to the storyboard, set the class name to *NakedTableViewController*, thereby using *Dynamic Prototypes* as *Content*, then I set the *Table View Cell Style* to *Right Detail* and I also set the cell identifier to *MyCellId*.

This is the code I use:

**NakedTableViewController**

```
partial class NakedTableViewController : UITableViewController
{

    public NakedTableViewController (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        TableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse (typeof(UITableViewCell), NakedTableViewSource.MyCellId);
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();


        TableView.Source = new NakedTableViewSource ();
    }
}
```

**NakedTableViewSource**

```
public class NakedTableViewSource : UITableViewSource
{
    public static readonly NSString MyCellId = new NSString ("MyCellId");

    public NakedTableViewSource ()
    {
    }

    public override nint NumberOfSections (UITableView tableView)
    {
        // TODO: return the actual number of sections
        return 1;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection (UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        // TODO: return the actual number of items in the section
        return 1;
    }

    public override string TitleForHeader (UITableView tableView, nint section)
    {
        return "Header";
    }

    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (MyCellId) as UITableViewCell;
        //          if (cell == null)
        //              cell = new UITableViewCell ();

        // TODO: populate the cell with the appropriate data based on the indexPath
        cell.TextLabel.Text = "TextLabel";
        cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = "DetailTextLabel";

        return cell;
    }
```

As you can see I'm using the newer cell reuse pattern.

The app crashes when I try to set the `DetailTextLabel`:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

So it seems the style `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` is not correctly registered and the setting of the detail label fails. What I'm doing wrong?

**Edit:**

StackTrace:

```
  at TestNakedTableView.NakedTableViewSource.GetCell (UIKit.UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath) [0x00028] in /Users/some-user/Projects/TestNakedTableView/TestNakedTableView/NakedTableViewSource.cs:47 
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, IntPtr principal, IntPtr delegate) [0x00005] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:62 
  at UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x00038] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:46 
  at TestNakedTableView.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/some-user/Projects/TestNakedTableView/TestNakedTableView/Main.cs:17
```

Comment: Do you have the stack trace information?  That would be helpful to see exactly at what point it's failing.  Since you're passing in a literal string, it sounds like something in (or called by) DetailTextLabel.Text isn't instantiated properly

Comment: @Taegost: I added the stack trace. Hope it's the correct one (Instance > base > base > StackTrace).

Comment: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/tables/part_3_-_customizing_a_table's_appearance/

Comment: @vijeesh: The examples all use the old reuse pattern (before iOS 6). Do you have found an example where the new pattern is used? I think that I can't use the default cell styles in custom cells.

Comment: Judging by the stack trace information, I think you may be looking in the wrong place.  It looks to me like the exception is being generated by the call to GetCell() in UIApplicationMain.  I would put some debugging code right before the call to GetCell() to make sure that the objects you're passing in as tableView and indexPath have been instantiated

Comment: FWIW: I *HATE* the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error in Visual Studio, it never tells you *which* object reference, you have to guess...

Comment: @Taegost: I know where it comes from. If I look into the cell you can see all properties. One of the properties is `DetailTextLabel`. It is null. If I select the basic style and don't use the `DetailTextLabel` the code works as desired. So it seems that the setup of `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`  or `Right Detail` isn't done correctly. The question is where should this be done? I did this within the iOS Designer and I'm using the "new" reuse pattern ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

Solution:

```
[Export("initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:")]
public MyCustomCell(UITableViewCellStyle style, NSString cellIdentifier)
        : base(SomeConstantValue, UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, cellIdentifier)
{

}
```

Source: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/54047/#Comment_54047

**Previous Answer:**

I think you are just missing the initialiser

```
if (cell == null) {
    cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, MyCellId);
}
```

So the full code would be:

```
 public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (MyCellId) as UITableViewCell;

        if (cell == null) {
             cell = new UITableViewCell (UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, MyCellId);
        }

        cell.TextLabel.Text = "TextLabel";
        cell.DetailTextLabel.Text = "DetailTextLabel";

        return cell;
    }
```

[1] http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/content_controls/tables/specify_the_cell_type/

Comment: The initialiser you mean is used in the old pattern (before iOS 6). In the new pattern you use `RegisterClassForCellReuse` and `DequeueReusableCell` so that the creation isn't needed anymore. Nevertheless I tried your code, but it didn't worked. Do you know when it works? It works when I don't use `RegisterClassForCellReuse`. So the question is why doesn't it work with the new reuse pattern since iOS 6 that should be the approach which should be used ...

Comment: I found a discussion on Xamarin's forums related to this. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/11344/cannot-set-uitableviewcell-style-if-using-reuse-pattern-with-registerclassforcellreuse-xibless-view

Comment: You should edit your answer and add the code from the link you posted. I tried something similar, but I didn't used the `Export` attribute.